# How to keep Onsen UI tabbar height after pushPage?

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I'm developing iOS/Android app using Monaca + Onsen UI. I'm using the following HTML structure for each page:

**tabbar.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-tabbar var="mainTb">
    <ons-tabbar-item no-reload icon="home" label="HOME" page="home.html" active="true">
    </ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item no-reload icon="talk" label="TALK" page="talkList.html">
    </ons-tabbar-item>
    ...
  </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>
```

**talkList.html**

```
<ons-page ng-controller="TalkListController">

  <!-- This is the "Navigation bar" -->
  <ons-toolbar>
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="fnShowGlobalMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="ic_global"></ons-icon>
    </ons-toolbar-button>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <!-- The list of talk -->
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item ng-repeat="r in talkRow" ng-click="showTalk(r.talkCode)">
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col>
          <div>
            {{r.userName}}
          </div>
          <!-- Some talk list info... -->
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>

</ons-page>
```

**talkDetail.html**

```
<ons-page ng-controller="TalkDetailController">

  <!-- This page have "Go back" icon instead of "Global Menu" -->
  <ons-toolbar>
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="fnShowGlobalMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="ic_global"></ons-icon>
    </ons-toolbar-button>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <!-- This is where message bubbles show up for users. -->
  <ons-list-item ng-repeat="r in messageRow" repeat-done="toBottom()">
    ...
  </ons-list-item>

  <!-- This is text area to enter message to send. -->
  <ons-bottom-toolbar>
    ..
  </ons-bottom-toolbar>

</ons-page>
```

Basically, the navigation takes two steps to show talkDetail which shows the users talk in timeline. The user taps tabbar item "TALK", then it navigates to talklist.html. The user next choice which one to talk to, and taps one of ons-list-item which invoke the `showTalk()`. This `showTalk()` is simply `this._scope.appRoot.pushPage(pageName, params);`

The code works almost perfectly, except when the page is moving to talkDetail.html. When navigate from talkList.html to talkDetail.html, the "navigation bar" (ons-toolbar) in talkDetail.html shrinks its height, makes the title text and "back button" in that area harder to tap.

[Tabbar navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNJpy.jpg)

This happens only in iOS device and not in Android.

Is there any way to fix this ? I have tried to "override" css but I don't know whether that's the proper way. Sorry for noob question. I'm quite new to Onsen UI and Monaca...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you can see in iOS the toolbar background includes the status bar of the OS. Onsen UI has an auto status bar fill feature which finds the appropriate toolbars and makes them larger.

It seems that your structure is maybe a little strange and causes Onsen UI to think that that specific toolbar doesn't need to be larger.

The proper way to solve this would be to inspect your structure and see why it doesn't think that it's needed. If you fix the cause then everything will work without further changes.

The implementation of that feature has gone trough some changes so actually mentioning the version which you are using may be useful. If you're using Onsen 2 the implementation will add a `status-bar-fill` attribute to the pages which thinks need it. For Onsen 1 the implementation is a bit different so inspecting may be a little hard.

Unfortunately I am not really sure that I have a clear enough understanding of your structure that I can point out the mistake. You could make a codepen with this example, so that we can understand the situation a little better. Right now I can only see a tabbar and some pages, however you said you are using something like `this._scope.appRoot.pushPage(pageName, params)` which sounds like a navigator, which isn't mentioned elsewhere.

And about overriding the css - it's not really the proper way to fix it, however if the other way is taking too much time and effort you might want to consider it. And if you're not really interested in changing the background of the status bar you could simply do `ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill()` and `body {top: 20px}` in iOS.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Perhaps the reason why Onsen tries to shrink its toolbar could be the talkDetail.html doesn't have the ons-tabbar, as shown in tabbar.html. Since Android keeps its tabbar's height without any code, I couldn't find any code to "adjust" the height of talkDetail.html. The page navigation is done by that pushPage and it navigates any pages without ons-navigator (I don't know this is bad structure design or not...). I'll take a look at codepen and disableAutoStatusBarFill(). Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem. Firstly my project using Onsen UI 1 (not 2) so changing attribute is not an option. Next I have tried disableAutoStatusBarFill, however it requires to be set before Onsen's initialise phase.

Comment: So I've decided to go on css way. Currently I'm overriding `.navigation-bar` and its height. iOS's toolbar problem is solved. But then Android's toolbar changed, as I expected...
Is there any way like `.navigation-bar--android` which only works for iOS? When I tried to use `--android`, strangely my Android version of that page does not use that layout. What I'm trying to achieve is to change the height of the specific page's toolbar (**talkDetail.html**), not for an entire app's.

Comment: @Köttur - yes the disable should be before you call `ons.bootstrap` or the `angular.module` part where you inject Onsen. About this `--android` - since iOS is the default design there is no specific class only for it. If you want you could cheat your way with a more complex selector like `.navigation-bar:not(.navigation-bar--android)`. And to make it specific for that element you can add an id. So it can be something like `#taskDetailToolbar:not(.navigation-bar--android)`.

Comment: Alternatively you can also add a specific class/id/styles in your `pageinit` listener for the `taskDetali` page. Using js for this is kindof ugly, but if all else fails you could try it. In that case you should have `ons.platform` and it's methods to check the conditions. I think for this you would need something like https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons.platform.html#method-isIOS7above

Comment: Thank you for advice, @Ilia Yatchev. After spent a lot of hours, I've finally managed to work around this problem by using `ons.platform` and querySelector to manipulate the `taskDetail` css for iOS. Yes, it's kind of ugly but for now, I believe this is the best way. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry to hear that it was the best way (it's kinda hacky), but at least I'm glad that the problem is solved. Maybe in a future project you could also try Onsen 2, as this may not be an issue over there. Good luck with your app!